# Using jQuery .attr to replace image inside conditional comment, not working

Tags: jquery, conditional-comments

I'm trying to show a different image to site visitors using IE 8 or older, perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems this should be working, any help is appreciated.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    $("#myImage").attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/TRTheme/images/Chester-4317.jpg");
  </script>
<![endif]-->

<div id="mapOhio"> <img id="myImage" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ohioMap.png" width="253" height="285" alt="Image of a map of Ohio." usemap="#image_map" border="0"/> </div>
```

Comment: You are trying to access the element before it exists. Reverse the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the element before it exists. Reverse the order. Answer in comments, thanks to Felix King.

Answer (score 2):

Add your script in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myImage").attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/TRTheme/images/Chester-4317.jpg");
}
```

Comment: For some reason your suggestion doesn't end up working, I reversed the order like Felix suggested and that worked, out of curiosity I then put the script inside document ready and it no longer switches out the image, I created a pastebin if you don't mind taking a look, http://pastebin.com/EqA9BV2u I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.